# VBA Loan Amortizing

Tags: excel, vba, schedule

I have seen on here how to Amortize a single Loan through this website and I was able to get it to work using the code below. But I am now trying to amortize multiple loans at the same time and produce the aggregate information at the end. I couldn't find anything online on how to do this, any ideas on where to start?

Thanks in Advance

```
Sub LoanAmort()

'take user inputs from top of the sheet Rate, Term, Orignal
'declares these as variables

Dim Rate, Term, Orignal, Payment

'telling VBA where these variables are

Rate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
Term = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
OrigBal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

'Calc PMT
Payment = PMT((Rate / 12), Term, -OrigBal)

'Declare the outputs

Dim BeginBal, Interest, Principal, EndBal

'Declare output Rows

OutputRow = 7

'Delete all previous information

Range(Cells(OutputRow + 1, 1), Cells(10000, 6)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

'Fill in rows

BeginBal = OrigBal

For rowNum = 1 To Term
    Interest = BeginBal * (Rate / 12)
    Principal = Payment - Interest
    EndBal = BeginBal - Principal

    'populate the cells

    Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 1).Value = rowNum
    Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 2).Value = BeginBal
    Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 3).Value = Payment
    Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 4).Value = Interest
    Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 5).Value = Principal
    Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 6).Value = EndBal

       BeginBal = EndBal
    Next rowNum
'Formatting

    Range(Cells(OutputRow + 1, 2), Cells(OutputRow + Term, 6)).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,###.#0"

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you mean by "multiple loans" with respect to your data layout.  Where is the information for the other loans - on other sheets (i.e. you just want to do what you are doing in your current code, but using multiple sheets), or in other columns (in which case, where are you putting the output, or do you just want the single "total" output)?

Comment: So I Have one sheet with loan information, for simplicity just say 2 loans

The info for the first one is:
Term     Rate        Balance
360          5%           100,000
360          6%            100,000

I am trying to take the info from this sheet, amortize the loans and show the totals outputs in the aggregate for the loan pool. Example: the PMT in period 1, would be the combined Payment of each loan.

Comment: I will post an answer, but it is a **guess** based on a **possible** data layout you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that information for your multiple loans are in rows 1 to 3 of columns B, C, D, etc, then you are probably wanting to just loop over those columns:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoanAmort()
    Dim Rate As Double, Term As Long, OrigBal As Double, Payment As Double
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim colNum As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim OutputRow As Long
    Dim BeginBal As Double, Interest As Double, Principal As Double, EndBal As Double

    'Declare output Rows
    OutputRow = 7

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' I'm lazy and don't want to keep typing Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Delete all previous information
        .Range(.Cells(OutputRow + 1, 1), .Cells(10000, 6)).ClearContents

        'Find last column
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Loop through each column
        For colNum = 2 To lastCol
            'telling VBA where these variables are
            Rate = .Cells(1, colNum).Value
            Term = .Cells(2, colNum).Value
            OrigBal = .Cells(3, colNum).Value

            'Calc PMT
            Payment = Pmt((Rate / 12), Term, -OrigBal)

            'Fill in rows
            BeginBal = OrigBal

            For rowNum = 1 To Term
                Interest = BeginBal * (Rate / 12)
                Principal = Payment - Interest
                EndBal = BeginBal - Principal

                'populate the cells

                .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 1).Value = rowNum
                .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 2).Value = .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 2).Value + BeginBal
                .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 3).Value = .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 3).Value + Payment
                .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 4).Value = .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 4).Value + Interest
                .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 5).Value = .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 5).Value + Principal
                .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 6).Value = .Cells(OutputRow + rowNum, 6).Value + EndBal

                BeginBal = EndBal
            Next
        Next

        'Formatting
        .Range(.Cells(OutputRow + 1, 2), .Cells(OutputRow + Term, 6)).NumberFormat = "$#,###.#0"
    End With
End Sub
```